# How to ensure only one pod runs on my node in GKE?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

In my application, I have a rest server which locally interacts with a database via the command line (it's a long story).  Anyway, the database is mounted in a local ssd on the node.  I can guarantee that only pods of that type will by scheduled in the node pool, as I have tainted the nodes and added tolerances to my pods.

What I want to know is, how can I prevent kubernetes from scheduling multiple instances of my pod on a single node?  I want to avoid this as I want my pod to be able to consume as much CPU as possible, and I also don't want multiple pods to interact via the local ssd.

How do I prevent scheduling of more than one pod of my type onto the node?  I was thinking daemon sets at first, but I think down the line, I want to set my node pool to auto scale, that way when I have n nodes in my pool, and I request n+1 replicas, the node pool automatically scales up.

Comment: I think you just create a daemonset and setup node scaling independent of this. when a new node is added , a pod will be automatically run on that. I see that a cleaner way

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Daemonsets`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/) in combination with [`nodeSelector` or `affinity`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/#running-pods-on-only-some-nodes). Alternatively you could configure [`podAntiAffinity`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#never-co-located-in-the-same-node) on your `Pod`s, for example:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: rest-server
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: rest-server
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: rest-server
    spec:
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - labelSelector:
              matchExpressions:
              - key: app
                operator: In
                values:
                - rest-server
            topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
      containers:
      - name: rest-server
        image: nginx:1.12-alpine
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you are trying to achieve, [DaemonSets](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/daemonset) might not be a complete answer, because DaemonSet is NOT auto scaled, and it will only place a pod in a new node; when you add new nodes to your pool.

If you are looking to modify your workload with n+1 replicas,it’s better to use [podAntiAffinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#never-co-located-in-the-same-node),  [controlling scheduling with node taints](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/node-taints) and cluster [autoscaler](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-autoscaler); this will guarantee that a new node will be added when you increase your pods and deleted when you scale down your pods:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
 name: echoheaders
spec:
 replicas: 1
 template:
   metadata:
     labels:
       app: echoheaders
   spec:
     affinity:
       podAntiAffinity:
         requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
         - labelSelector:
             matchExpressions:
             - key: app
               operator: In
               values:
               - echoheaders
           topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
     containers:
     - name: echoheaders
       image: k8s.gcr.io/echoserver:1.4
       ports:
       - containerPort: 8080
     tolerations:
     - key: dedicated
       operator: Equal
       value: experimental
       effect: NoSchedule
```

Comment: ReplicationController is [not recommended](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/replicationcontroller/) anymore. Instead use a Deployment that configures a ReplicaSet to set up replication.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest two ways of going about this. One is to restrict the number of pods schedulable on a node, and the other is to assign the pod to a given node while requesting for the entirety of the resources available in the node.

**1. Restricting number of schedulable pods per node**

You can set this restriction when you're creating a new cluster, however it is limiting if later you change your mind. Find the following field in the advanced settings as you create the cluster.

[image]

**2. Assigning pod to specific node and occupying all resources**

Another option is to set the resource request numbers such that they match a node's resources, and assign it to a given node, using the `nodeSelector` and `labels`.

Check out [this link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/) for how to assign pods to a specific node.